# How can I detect TabController begin change event in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I do not know how can i detect `TabController` beginning changed event in Flutter.

example:

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Text('Tab1'),
            Text('Tab2'),
            Text('Tab3'),
          ],
          controller: _controller,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text('tab1'),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text('tab2'),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Text('tab3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
          if (_controller.indexIsChanging) {
            return;
          }
          /// if you fast enough, you can press this button during index is changing
          print(_controller.index);
        }, child: Text('button'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`_controller.indexIsChanging` is not working in this case, so I need to detect when the TabController starts changing, any suggestion will be very helpful!

I tried to use `addListener`, but this callback will be called nearly once the TabController completes its changing, which is not what I want, I want to add a Listener when the TabController begins changing or pre-changing.

Comment: if you want to detect tab change, then why have you added within a button's on pressed instead of callback?

Comment: @OMiShah what i want to achieve is when TabController is changing, the button can not be clicked, but indexIsChanging is not useful in this case, so i need to find a way to detect TabController begin changing and end changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_controller.animation` value to figure out the status of the tab:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

  _controller.animation!.addListener(() {
    print('TabController is changing...');
    print(_controller.animation!.value);
  });
}
```